# UTF-8 sometimes wrong output

Tags: java, utf-8, console

I have a problem with writing output string into Windows console but this is true only for my machine (Windows 8.1) my friend have Windows 7 and everithing works fine. Here is test code:

```
package test;

import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
public class EncodingTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException  {

       //First try
       System.out.println("ľščťžýáíéúäôň");

       //Second try
       PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
       out.println("ľščťžýáíéúäôň");

    }

}
```

In NetBeans everithing works fine outpout is OK. But If I try to run code from Windows CMD output is :

```
??????áíéúäô?
─╛┼í─ì┼Ñ┼╛├╜├í├¡├⌐├║├ñ├┤┼ê
```

But this is case only on my machine, on any other this wors fine !?

Comment: And what is shown on your friend's machine for that code? Also, does the friend take your compiled classes or your source code, compiling again at his end?

Comment: The code page in cmd needs to be set to the code page which supports those special characters. (`chcp`)

Comment: @nhahtdh I believe the only way to get there is setting the system-wide code page, which is usually done at installation time and requires a restart when changed later.

Comment: Marko yes it is, he took my compiled classes and output is just expected "ľščťžýáíéúäôň"

Answer (score 0):

1. Open/run `cmd.exe`
2. Click on the icon at the top-left corner
3. Select properties
4. Then "Font" bar
5. Select "Lucida Console" and OK.
6. Write `chcp 1252` or `chcp 65001`
7. It should now print Unicode.

Comment: Hmm this doesn't work it prints : ?š??žýáíéúäô?
Ä¾Å¡ÄÅ¥Å¾Ã½Ã¡Ã­Ã©ÃºÃ¤Ã´Åˆ

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the default encoding:

```
Charset.defaultCharset()
```

The default encoding must be specified as a argument to the jvm at the program start

```
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 test.EncodingTest.Main
```

Comment: With this it print output looks like: ľščťžýáíéúäôň�íéúäôňäôň�ň�
ľščťžýáíéúäôň�íéúäôňäôň�ň� It looks like everithing is printed ok but there is additional chars printed out !?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have found where was a problem. In windows Regional setting on last tab (Administrative) for option Language for non-Unicode programs it was US (English).
After I have change this to Slovak (Slovakia) and ofcourse restarting Win everithing works fine :-)